# Is there an easier way to copy image elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I am copying image elements from one XML file into a new one using XSLT. I am using the following template to copy an image element, but I think there is a simpler way to do this.

…

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="art_id"/>
```

…

```
<xsl:template match="art_id"><xsl:text>
</xsl:text><image><art_id>
<xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@href"/></xsl:attribute>
</art_id></image>
</xsl:template>
```

The "new" XML image element is an exact copy of the original.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a simpler way, but if you use attribute value templates, you can do this:

```
<xsl:template match="art_id">
    <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    <image>
        <art_id href="{@href}"/>
    </image>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you talked about making an "exact copy", `xsl:copy-of` would be an option.

```
<xsl:template match="art_id">
  <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
  <image>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </image>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>` to just copy the attributes? `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>` will copy the text() also

Comment: `select="@*"` would copy the attributes without copying the `art_id` element. So `image` would get the attributes, which is not what I see the OP doing. Since the OP said "exact copy", I'm not seeing an issue with copying `text()` too.